# Phonegap: confusing config files

Tags: android, cordova

im trying to get a simple app running on my galaxy s3 using Eclipse with latest Android SDK.
First i downloaded the latest phonegap with the npm command using "npm install -g phonegap".
This installed me the phonegap and cordova commands.

Using cordova, i created my test app with:

```
cordova create test "com.helloworld.mobile" "test"
cd test
cordova platform add android
cordova build
```

all of this worked fine. then i created a new android project in eclipse using the platforms folder inside test/ as source.
Then i coded the deviceready part which gets triggered successfully.
But i have no access to the device variable to access device info, so i guess i forgot to add the permissions into the XMLs to get access to my hardware.

Now im confused, which one of these i have to change, and each XML looks different.
I have AndroidManifest.xml in my root folder. Then a config.xml in my assets/www folder and another config.xml in my res/xml/ folder. Both config.xml look similar, but are not the same.

I tried different changes using uses-permission or feature or plugin. I even created plugins.xml in res/xml, but it didnt help. Documentation doesn't help.

How to set up these config files correctly so i get access to my device via phonegap?
I simply tried to print device.cordova or device.model or whatever, but device remains undefined, even after deviceready fired off.

PS: Deploying this app on my phone works fine, even the debugger runs, so i can see the error messages from javascript. so it must be a permission problem i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only change AndroidManifest.xml in platforms/android folder. All permissions are there. Plugins should be added to res/xml/config.xml as well, but if you are using CLI you shouldn't change anything there.